# Nested partitioning and ranking in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, ranking

Below is how the data looks like-
[image]

I want to sort this data on different levels to achieve the final output.

**Level 1:**
Whenever there are duplicate values for name, I want to get the least ranking for each distinct (id, name,last_name, gender) tuple.

**Level 1 Result:**
[image]

**Level 2:**
In level 2, I want to get the least ranking for each gender category for a particular name.

**Level 2 Result:**
[image]

**Final output:**
For each name, if 'male' and 'female' rank is the same then return the whichever occurs first in the table. If it is different return the record with the least rank.

**Final result expected-**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY ranking, id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

I do suspect that you can just partition by name:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by ranking, id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

The second sort criteria on `id` breaks the tie.